# Spresense SDKでのwget_postでの1500バイト以上での送信について

Tags: spresense, http

sdk/system/netutils/webclient/webclient.cを改変して、バイナリファイルを送信しようとしていて気づいたのですが、
1500バイト以上のテキスト(バッファー)を送信しようとすると、ちゃんとバッファーのバイト数分送信しようとするのですが、
中身は先頭の1500バイトを繰り返して送っているように見えます。

wget_baseはバイナリに対応していないのは把握しており、wget_baseをコピーしてwget_base_post_binaryという別の関数を作って試していますが、大元ののwget_baseに問題がありそうでした。

具体的には、以下の部分が問題かと思われます。

sdk/system/netutils/webclient/webclient.c: wget_base(FAR const char *url, FAR char *buffer, int buflen,
                     wget_callback_t callback, FAR void *arg,
                     FAR const char *posts, uint8_t mode)
の中の、

```
      do
        {
          ret = https ? tls_socket_write(sockfd, buffer, len)
                      : send(sockfd, buffer, len, 0);
          if (ret < 0)
            {
              nerr("ERROR: send failed: %d\n", errno);
              goto errout;
            }
          len = len - ret;
        }
      while (len != 0);
```

という箇所ですが、

```
      char *p_buffer = buffer;
      do
        {
          ret = https ? tls_socket_write(sockfd, p_buffer, len)
                      : send(sockfd, p_buffer, len, 0);
          if (ret < 0)
            {
              nerr("ERROR: send failed: %d\n", errno);
              goto errout;
            }
          p_buffer += ret;
          len = len - ret;
        }
      while (len != 0);
```

と書く必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

SDKに含まれるwebclient.cのwget_baseですが、ご指摘の通り誤りがございました。
修正をGithubへ [Pull Request](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/pull/46) を作成し、反映いたしました。

この度はSDKへのフィードバックをありがとうございました。
今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: 無事マージされたようで、ありがとうございます！